# Splitting JSON array values to k/v and sequencing

Tags: json, python-3.x, data-structures, jsonparser

So I managed to split the following JSON data to k/v pairs

```json
"tags": [
    "category--Cola",
    "sugar--3.000000",
    "barcode--cola001",
    "barcode--cola001_1",
    "language--en",
    "sku--cola_classic",
    "sku--cola_cherry",
]
```

like so...

```python
t = product['tags']
t_filtered = [k for k in t if '--' in k]
product['tags'] = dict(s.split('--') for s in t_filtered)
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```json
{
"category": [Cola],
"sugar":[3.0],
"barcode":[cola001,cola001_1],
"language":[en],
"sku": [cola_classic, cola_cherry],

}
```

So I tried this... (ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```python
product['tags'] = dict(s.split('--') for s in t_filtered)
        s = product['tags']
        d = {}
        for k, v in s:
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        print(d)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Also, just to verify `s` is a `<classic 'dict'>` so I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: what is `t_filtered` ?

Comment: Your problem is that `dict(s.split('--') for s in t_filtered)` is not the right way to build a dictionary. You should give a keys values pairs.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the code above: t = product['tags']
        t_filtered = [k for k in t if '--' in k]